# Http upload, save the mod/write date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

On my website i can upload files. I then use file[indx].SaveAs(path) to save the file however i notice the modify date is the current date and the creation date is 1second after that. Is there a way i can get the correct modify/write date from the client?

Comment: Are you uploading images?  If so, you can grab the date taken from the EXIF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No. Not the way you're doing things.

Longer answer: You could... but only with something client-side. You would need something on the users' machines to read that information (ie a Java applet) and send it out-of-band alongside the HTTP upload.